# How to keep undo history after closing vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I close VS Code and open again I lose all undo history. Is possible to keep it after closing the editor?

Comment: No, there's no record kept of the undo history on closure on any editor I've ever seen. You can't ask about an extension here, because asking for recommendations for off-site resources is off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: This is why source control was invented.  You can always go back to an earlier version of a file.

Comment: @KenWhite I think people coming from shell who may be familiar with nvim are looking for a similar feature to `undofile`. Just in case you or anyone is curious.
https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'undofile'

Comment: @MarkRansom Except when you have a pre-commit hook that modifies your code so it isn't your version that gets committed thus losing your work.

Answer (score 3):

A persistent undo/redo stack was introduced a while ago, and the default configuration sets it to discard that stack when a file is 'closed', which includes saving a file. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_keep-undo-stack-when-reopening-files

The configuration item is called: files.restoreUndoStack and is available in the standard editor preferences as well.

This is, however, kept as long as you simply close and re-open the editor.

If you are looking for a different feature, i.e. keeping the history when you save, close and open a file, that is a different configuration.

A later version introduced this option as well, as seen in the changelog: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#cross-file-undo-in-closed-files